# IE 7 bug - embedded white is removed when text is placed in innerHTML

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

It seems like the embedded spaces are removed from the text I put into innerHTML.  Is there a work around?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
        <script>
            function copydiv()
            {
                var text = document.getElementById("copyfrom").innerHTML;
                //In real life "text" is from a AJAX call to a server.
                var temp = document.createElement( "TD" );
                temp.innerHTML = text
                var tr = document.getElementById("copyto");
                tr.appendChild(temp);
            }

        </script>
    <head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr id="copyto">
                <td id="copyfrom">
                    <a style="white-space: pre;">A               Z</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="button" onclick="copydiv();">Test</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Grae

PS: Sorry about the spacing.

Comment: What's the purpose of the extra space in the tags? What are you using to view the value of `innerHTML`?

Comment: The extra spaces are part of the data.  The main point is to pre format the data.  However, once I append the data into innerHTML the ebbeded spaces disappear, so using a pre tg is wasted.

Comment: First off, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897(v=vs.85).aspx) may help. Second some things to consider, a.) MS is about to move away from it's support for IE9- as well as MANY high end sights (like FB) are already dropping support for pre9IE's, b.) second, as I've spoke w my current Supervisory Board about, continuing to support out-dated tech is exactly why it's takin this long for things like 4g, 3d, and other flashy new items to come to market and should really not be encouraged, c.) as has been proven, at least in the SouthEast US (my area) if forced, ppl will upgrade

Comment: @SpYk3HH Atleast for now ie7 is required.

Comment: That's a real bummer, I think most of us all can agree, until MS steps up their game and plays nice with already existing inet tech, we'll all be glad when ie's share of use online drops below 10%

Answer (score 1):

> //In real life "text" is from a AJAX call to a server.

Basically you have to wrap the htmlstring in a `<pre>`-element and remove it afterwards.

```
// a container
var div = document.createElement('div');
// wrap the text in a <pre>-element
div.innerHTML = '<pre>' + text + '<\/pre>';
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    pre = div.firstChild;
// move all childnodes from the <pre>-element to the DocumentFragment
while(pre.firstChild) {
    frag.appendChild(pre.firstChild);
}
// frag now holds the DOM nodes. Add it to the DOM with node.appendChild or
// simliar methods.
```

**Complete Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN'
    'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd'>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=EmulateIE7'>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <textarea id='copy-area' cols='20' rows='2'>
            &lt;span style="white-space: pre"&gt;|       |&lt;/span&gt;
        </textarea>
        <div id='paste-area'></div>
        <button id='add-html'>Add HTML</button>
        <button id='alert-innerhtml'>Alert innerHTML</button>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
'use strict';

function addEvent(node, evtType, callback) {
    if('addEventListener' in node) {
        node.addEventListener(evtType, callback, false);
    } else {
        node.attachEvent('on' + evtType, callback);
    }
}

var copyArea = document.getElementById('copy-area'),
    pasteArea = document.getElementById('paste-area');

addEvent(document.getElementById('add-html'), 'click', (function() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '|  |';
    var useWorkaround = div.innerHTML.length !== 4;
    return function(e) {
        var text = copyArea.value;
        var container;
        if(useWorkaround) {
            div.innerHTML = '<pre>' + text + '<\/pre>';
            container = div.firstChild;
        } else {
            div.innerHTML = text;
            container = div;
        }
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
        while(container.firstChild) {
            frag.appendChild(container.firstChild);
        }
        pasteArea.appendChild(frag);
    }
})());

addEvent(document.getElementById('alert-innerhtml'), 'click', function(e) {
    alert(pasteArea.innerHTML);
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Another Workaround With An Iframe**

This version respects `white-space: pre` and behaves better with newlines.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN'
    'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd'>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=EmulateIE7'>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <textarea id='copy-area' cols='20' rows='2'>
            &lt;span style="white-space: pre"&gt;|       |&lt;/span&gt;
        </textarea>
        <div id='paste-area'></div>
        <button id='add-html'>Add HTML</button>
        <button id='alert-innerhtml'>Alert innerHTML</button>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
'use strict';
function addEvent(node, type, callback) {
    if('addEventListener' in node) {
        node.addEventListener(type, callback, false);
    } else {
        node.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
    }
}

addEvent(document.getElementById('add-html'), 'click', (function() {
    var copyArea = document.getElementById('copy-area'),
        pasteArea = document.getElementById('paste-area'),
        div = document.createElement('div');

    function createFilledFragment(container) {
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
        while(container.firstChild) {
            frag.appendChild(container.firstChild);
        }
        return frag;
    }

    div.innerHTML = '|  |';
    var getFilledFragment = div.innerHTML.length === 4 ?
        // Firefox, ...
        function(text) {
            div.innerHTML = text;
            return createFilledFragment(div);
        } :
        // Workaround IE 7, IE 8, ...
        (function() {
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.style.display = 'none';
            var body = document.body;
            return function(text) {
                body.appendChild(iframe);
                var iframeDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
                iframeDoc.write(text);
                var frag = createFilledFragment(iframeDoc.body);
                body.removeChild(iframe);
                return frag;
            }
        })();

    return function(e) {
        pasteArea.appendChild(getFilledFragment(copyArea.value));
    };
})());

addEvent(document.getElementById('alert-innerhtml'), 'click', (function() {
    var pasteArea = document.getElementById('paste-area');
    return function(e) {
        alert(pasteArea.innerHTML);
    }
})());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Old**

Use [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode) and avoid this nasty innerHTML-property:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
        <script>
function copydiv() {
    var node = document.getElementById("copyfrom").cloneNode(true);
    node.removeAttribute('id');
    document.getElementById("copyto").appendChild(node);
}
        </script>
    <head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr id="copyto">
                <td id="copyfrom">
                    <a style="white-space: pre;">A               Z</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="button" onclick="copydiv();">Test</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

It should be faster anyway.

Comment: Hmm.. This is a great idea, but will not work for me.  I was just using this as an example.  In real life getting the text from from an AJAX call to the server.

Comment: Nice where, did you find this idea (The first one, where you wrap the sample in a pre tag)?  Is it copyrighted or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

I have only IE8 now with IE7 emulation, but I'm sure, `white-space` doesn't work because of, your document is in `quirksmode`.

Comment: I am not in quirks mode.  I am in ie-7 standards mode.

Comment: Which version of IE did you tested?

Comment: Did you try my sample with ie8?

Comment: Maybe it is only win 7.  Anyway I slice it though, I have to do it.